# How to show option saved in array in drop down list in php

Tags: php, arrays

I created dynamic drop down box(on change function of some other textbox)and have retrieved the drop down options according to some condition ,from sql database,which is saved in array. now that data is saved in array I want to display the array values as option in drop down list.

```
success: function(result){
     var pch=result.split('//');
     var plen=pch.length;
     var options='';
     $('#fid').html('');
     $('#fid').append('<tr><td><br><b>PROCESS NAME</b><br><br></td></tr><tr><td><select name="process_name" label="" id="prc" style="height:30px; margin-top:-5px; min-width:190px; width:auto;" ><option value="">Select any</option>');

    for(var j2=0;j2<plen-1;j2++){
        $('#fid').append('<option value="'+pch[j2]+'">'+pch[j2]+'</option>');
    }
    $('#fid').append('</select></td></tr>');
}
```

Comment: and what is error ?

Comment: options were not coming in drop box instead diplayed as a line below dropdown list.The code below by @Jayesh Chitroda helped and now its solved! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `.each()` to loop through all values and put it in div.

```js
var pch = ["Val 1","Val 2","Val 3","Val 4","Val 5","Val 6","Val 7"];
var str = "";

$('#fid').html('');
str ='<tr><td><br><b>PROCESS NAME</b><br><br></td></tr><tr><td><select name="process_name" label="" id="prc" style="height:30px; margin-top:-5px; min-width:190px; width:auto;" ><option value="">Select any</option>';


$.each(pch, function(i,v) {
  str += '<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>';
});

str += '</select></td></tr>';

$('#fid').append(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fid"></div>
```